# Product Names recognition / categorization

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, azure-cognitive-services, named-entity-recognition

I'm new to machine learning, so please forgive any mistake in this question...

## **PROBLEM DEFINITION**

We're working in a project which have these specific requirement:

1. The user takes a picture from a pharmacy shelf which contains a bunch of products (drugs) and uploads it to Azure
2. We are using Azure Cognitive Services to OCR the pictures and detect TEXT from them
3. The OCR, in most cases, will return a lot of text, much of it is useful but some lines we dont need them, also the OCR may return mispelled words (very similar to a product name)
4. We have a dictionary of product names/ recognized term (manually crafted (kind of vademecum))
5. What we need is for each line of text returned by the OCR:

   - Match against a Known product name/recognized term
   - Discard unknown words

## **EXAMPLE**

1. we have this image as an example:
   [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rucbK.jpg)
2. The OCR returns these lines (***in 2nd column (--->) our expected result***):

   - flex                           ---> *NULL*
   - F1ORAT1L                       ---> **FLORATIL**
   - FLORATI L 100                  ---> **FLORATIL**
   - FLORATIL 200                   ---> **FLORATIL**
   - FLORATIL AT 250                ---> **FLORATIL**
   - Enterogermina                  ---> **ENTEROGERMINA**
   - PROMOCAO                       ---> *NULL*
   - is 27.30                       ---> *NULL*
   - yces boulardii CNCM I          ---> *NULL*
   - VALE POR                       ---> *NULL*
   - TA BARATO                      ---> *NULL*

## **QUESTION**

1. The OCR may return mispelled words (very similar to products names) *see lines 2 and 3*. How do you recomend to implement this fuzzy matching?
2. We would like to join different types of products configurations (FLORATIL 100, FLORATIL 200, FLORATIL AT 250) to a main drug category = FLORATIL
3. How do you imagine the best pipeline to follow to solve this problem? we would like to use any algorithm available in Azure machine learning services, but we can use python or another stack

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needs definition, you could simply add Azure Search and get what you want:

- Call OCR
- For each item in OCR Result, call Azure Search (add `~`after each word and specify `queryType=full` to perform a fuzzy match, see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#example-3-fuzzy-search))
- Use the result of the search to get the highest matching item, and use the score provided to filter the non matching results if needed

You just have to setup your Azure Search with the dictionary you mentioned